# Mysql Select Query based on value from different table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is a very basic question, I apologize if someone has already asked this question..

I have a main table called 'item'. It has all the item(s) related information such as catalog,description,avail,price etc

I also have another table called 'activelisting' which only have one column 'catalog'.

Now I want to pull 'catalog','description', and 'avail' from 'item' table based on 'catalog' exists in 'activelisting' table. 
or another words everything from 'activelisting' table and matching records from 'item' table.

I have researched it a lot but I am unable to find working query.  I am using the following query..

```
SELECT t1.catalog, t1.description, t1.avail
FROM item t1
LEFT JOIN activelisting t2
ON t1.`Catalog` = t2.`Catalog`;
```

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You seem really close, but I think you're looking for an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Presuming the rows in active listing are unique.  Are they?

Comment: have you tried `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) instead of `LEFT JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` will guarantee that the value being joined on exists in both tables.

```
SELECT i.catalog, i.description, i.avail
FROM item i
INNER JOIN activelisting a ON i.catalog = a.catalog
```

`LEFT JOIN` will return all results in the left table, `item` and if there is not a row in `activelisting` with the same `catalog` then it will just return `NULL` for those columns. You are not currently selecting the potential `NULL` columns, so your current result should basically just be all of the entries in `item`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.catalog, t1.description, t1.avail FROM item t1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN activelisting t2 ON t1.Catalog = t2.Catalog;
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.catalog, t1.description, t1.avail FROM activelisting t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN item t1 ON t1.Catalog = t2.Catalog;
```

The first one for good visualizer. You have to use outer join just because you take all catalogs from activlisting table and matched catalog from item table.

Second one for better understanding.